# Nuxt 3 & BigQuery: No form data is inserted into BigQuery table after submit, but no errors also shown in the console

Tags: google-bigquery, axios, nuxtjs3, vue-options-api

I want submit a simple form which has only inputs such as name and email into Google bigquery. But once it is submitted, I encounter things as below:

1. Nothing is displayed in the Google BigQuery table. supposed to have form data (name, email) inside the table
2. weird html docs text on console (to refer as attached below)

[in console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IW5vz.png)

So, basically what I want to do is I submit a form into BigQuery and the form data is display in the table so that I can retrieve it later.

I'm using Nuxt v3, Vuetify, Axios, Options API to do it

Attached is the code below:

Inside /server/api/submit.js

```
import { BigQuery } from '@google-cloud/bigquery';

export default defineEventHandler(async (event) => {
  const { body } = event.request;

  // Parse the JSON request body to get the supervisor and activity fields
  const { name, email } = JSON.parse(body);

  // Insert the data into BigQuery
  const insertResult = await insertFormDataIntoBigQuery(name, email);

  return {
    statusCode: 200,
    body: {
      message: `Inserted ${insertResult.rowCount} rows into BigQuery`
    }
  };
});

async function insertFormDataIntoBigQuery(name, email) {
  const bigquery = new BigQuery('projectName');
  const datasetName = 'test';
  const tableName = 'form';
  const schema = [
    { name: 'name', type: 'STRING' },
    { name: 'email', type: 'STRING' }
  ];

  const data = { supervisor, activity };
  const options = {
    dataset: bigquery.dataset(datasetName),
    table: tableName,
    schema: schema,
    rows: [data]
  };

  const [result] = await bigquery.dataset(datasetName).table(tableName).insert(options);

  return result;
}
```

my vue page

```
<template>
    <v-container>
      <v-form @submit.prevent="submitForm">
        <v-text-field v-model="name" label="name" required></v-text-field>
        <v-text-field v-model="email" label="email" required></v-text-field>
        <v-btn type="submit">Submit</v-btn>
      </v-form>
    </v-container>
</template>

<script>
import axios from "axios";

export default {
    data: () => ({
        name: '',
        email: ''
    }),
    methods: {
    async submitForm() {
      try {
        console.log(this.name, this.email)
        const response = await axios.post('/api/submit', {
          name: this.name,
          email: this.email
        });
        console.log(response);
        this.name = '';
        this.email = '';
      } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

to add more context, I did put console.log() before `import { BigQuery } from '@google-cloud/bigquery';` and after `defineEventHandler` & `insertFormDataIntoBigQuery` to see if anything is showing up but no. Nothings logs out in the console.

Only `console.log(response);` and `console.log(this.name, this.email)` shows up in my console.

So how to actually insert data into BigQuery using Nuxt 3?

Notes: I'm using Application Default Credential (ADC) to authenticate instead of using GCP service account

I want my form to succesfully submit into Google BigQuery table but nothing is displayed in the table showing that it is actually inserted in it.